# Magento Category page not showing product list

Tags: magento2, php, error-message

I am new on magento. Please help me with this issue.

I moved my magento site from one system to another system. And after that this URL **localhost/magento/men/tops-men/hoodies-and-sweatshirts-men.htm**l is not showing products. It is showing **"We can't find products matching the selection."**

And to resolve this, I ran this command: **php bin/magento indexer:reindex** but it is showing :

> Catalog Search index process unknown error:
> {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"request
> [/magento2_product_1_v2/document/_mapping] contains unrecognized
> parameter:
> [include_type_name]"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"request
> [/magento2_product_1_v2/document/_mapping] contains unrecognized
> parameter: [include_type_name]"},"status":400}

Comment: Check is elasticseach is configured correctly and running on new system.

Comment: may be this url resolve your issue -> https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/151785/catalog-search-indexer-process-unknown-error-there-is-no-such-engine-mysql2

Comment: https://digitalstartup.co.uk/t/catalog-search-index-process-unknown-error/1722

Comment: @RahulBarot Please tell me how to check elasticsearch is configured correctly

Comment: Check the Composer package version for elasticsearch/elasticsearch. = > 

composer show elasticsearch/elasticsearch

Comment: elasticsearch is working on new system. I checked it from this 

curl -X GET 'http://localhost:9200'

and It is showing:

{
   "name":"OB_VPVo",
   "cluster_name":"elasticsearch",
   "cluster_uuid":"p6Eu38O0TNq20vHoYPiVDA",
   "version":{
      "number":"5.6.14",
      "build_hash":"f310fe9",
      "build_date":"2018-12-05T21:20:16.416Z",
      "build_snapshot":false,
      "lucene_version":"6.6.1"
   },
   "tagline":"You Know, for Search"
}

Comment: Thanks to all. After upgrading elasticsearch from 5.6.14 to 7.12.1 my issue has been resolved